# EXM: Adding "List-Unsubscribe" header to emails

Tags: exm

We are currently trying to improve spam-scores for our customers' email campaigns and have used the tool https://www.mail-tester.com/ which states that we are being penalized by not including a **List-Unsubscribe** header/functionality.

Does anyone know (or have implemented) functionality to the EXM pipeline that adds the List-Unsubscribe header to emails? Googling and the Sitecore knowledge base has failed me so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using EXM 3.3 (or later) this can be done by overriding the dispatchprovider. You'll find this element under /sitecore/exm/eds/dispatchManager in the configuration (Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSMTP.config or Sitecore.EDS.Providers.Dyn.config) e.g.

```
<dispatchManager defaultProvider="default">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="default" type="Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp.DispatchProvider, Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp">
            <param ref="exm/eds/connectionPool" />
            <param ref="exm/eds/environmentIdentifier" />
        </add>
    </providers>
</dispatchManager>
```

You'll need to override the SetMessageHeaders method e.g.

```
protected override void SetMessageHeaders(EmailMessage message)
{
    base.SetMessageHeaders(message);
    message.Headers.Set("Your-Header-Name", "Your-Value");
}
```

In **EXM 3.4** and later, this configuration element has changed and is now called

```
<dispatchProvider defaultProvider="default">
  <providers>
        <clear />
            <add name="default" type="Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp.DispatchProvider, Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp">
                <param ref="exm/eds/connectionPool" />
                <param ref="exm/eds/environmentIdentifier" />
            </add>
    </providers>
</dispatchProvider>
```

Comment: Is it me, or are your old and new snippets the same?

Comment: That's you :) <dispatchManager vs. <dispatchProvider

Comment: Touché, good sir

Comment: I am doing the same thing now. Question: how to get the context Contact ID from message.ContactId string which is somehow hashed?